# Movie where a red skinned devil looking creature finds fame

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a film where a red skinned looking creature is living in an arctic tundra and is a recluse until he is found by a woman and becomes a celebrity. He falls in love with the woman and doesn't do well with being a celebrity as he starts drinking and living a hedonistic lifestyle which drives the woman away and he goes back to his arctic home.

I remember seeing it years ago, but this is all that I remember.

Comment: Please visit https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question and see if you can [edit] in more details. Like when did you watch this? Was it in theatres? DVD? TV? Netflix? Also, if someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like [*No Such Thing*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0248190/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), a 2001 movie with Sarah Polley.  It involves a woman going to meet an alcoholic hedonistic monster in an isolated place in Iceland to make a news story about him, and also to find her fiancee.  She brings the monster back to New York, where he becomes a celebrity.  Things degenerate as he gets experimented on by scientists to find the secret of his indestructability.  There is a full synopsis [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Such_Thing_(film)), and it mostly hits your story beats.

Comment: On a slightly related note, Sarah Polley stole my moms umbrella at a wedding they both happened to be attending.  I will get it back one day.

Comment: This is it. Omg. Thank you. Its been on my mind for nearly 20 years. Thank you so much. I have no O'Dea why I thought he was red. I know he had horns and he was angry. Thank you!!!

Comment: @Barrons01 Glad this was found for you. As this is correct you can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark next to the voting buttons as per the [tour].